# Hook into update/install process callback (Update manager) - providing a custom message after installing a module from URL

Tags: updating, installation

After installing a module from a given URL (on `admin/modules/install`), I can see the following messages:

[image: Module installation (Update manager)]

So it outputs 3 links in the "Next steps" list, but **I would like to hook into the update callback process, extend this list, and provide another link** which points to a callback page defined by my own module, where I can enable the module immediately. I don't need help for the latter, only for **the way to hook into the process of altering/extending the messages** in the result.
After hooking into to the process of generating the output (hooking into the callback process), I will need to know the module's machine name.

This is what the expected result would look like:

[image: Update manager - new link]

OR

[image: Update manager - new link]

OR

[image: Update manager - new link]

**What would be the appropriate way to provide custom messages in the update callback?**

The *"Installation was completed successfully."* text is defined by [`update_authorize_install_batch_finished()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!update!update.authorize.inc/function/update_authorize_install_batch_finished/7) in `modules/update/update.authorize.inc` (and gets into `$_SESSION['authorize_results']['page_message']` as an array), and the `"Next steps"` list is provided by `ModuleUpdater::postInstallTasks` in `modules/system/system.updater.inc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to extend the `ModuleUpdater` class to provide your own `postInstallTasks()` implementation:

```
class MyModuleUpdater extends ModuleUpdater {

  /**
   * Overrides ModuleUpdater::postInstallTasks().
   */
  public function postInstallTasks() {
    return array(
      l(t('Enable @module module', array('@module' => $this->title)), 'admin/modules/enable/' . $this->name),
      l(t('Install another module'), 'admin/modules/install'),
      l(t('Enable newly added modules'), 'admin/modules'),
      l(t('Administration pages'), 'admin'),
    );
  }    

}
```

And then implement [`hook_updater_info_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_updater_info_alter/7) to let Drupal know you want to use that class instead of the default:

```
function MYMODULE_updater_info_alter(&$updaters) {
  $updaters['module']['class'] = 'MyModuleUpdater';
}
```

You'll also need to add this to your module's .info file so the new class can be autoloaded:

```
files[] = path/to/MyModuleUpdater.php
```

Once you clear the caches the change should take effect.

Comment: Wow, Clive, that was quick and perfect! :) The module's human readable name (taken from the *.info file's name property) is available in the class with `$this->title`, and the machine name is available with `$this->name`. So I managed to output the desired link like this: `l(t('Enable "@project_title" module (machine name: "@project_name")', array('@project_title' => $this->title, '@project_name' => $this->name)), 'admin/modules/enable/'.$this->name)`. It works: http://i.imgur.com/ibQUnqG.png. :) Just an interesting fact: you can not use the `%` as a placeholder: http://i.imgur.com/hbJ1ysp.png

Comment: +1 and accepted, thank you very much! :) (Could you also include using the `$this->name` variable in the `l()` function in your answer to help others? Thanks :) )

Comment: Awesome, I was interested to know it that would work too ;) I've added your changes in, good finds

Comment: I didn't think it's so easy :) Thanks for adding the additional information in your answer!